# c# generics methods and List

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to understand why the code below does not work and how to fix it.

if T is double or long Why T does not accept casting of double or long?

```
    private IList<T> GetGenericList<T>(bool isDouble) where T : double, long
    {
        IList<T> Result = new List<T>();

        if (isDouble)
        {
            T Value = 2.5; // does not compile
            Result.Add(Value);
        }
        else
        {
            T Value = 2; // does not compile
            Result.Add(Value);
        }

        return Result;
    }
```

[UPDATE]
Ok people don't be nervous! Let me understand what you said! :)

What is the principle of generics in c#?

If I change de code to the below example? (Get out of the box, It is only one example, please ignore de rules (if (isDouble), whatever)

```
private IList<T> GetGenericList<T>(//whatever you want of param...
) where T : double
{
    IList<T> Result = new List<T>();
    T Value = 2.5; // does not compile
    Result.Add(Value);
    return Result;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There's no reason why you would need to provide isDouble as an arg; the type of T can be determined at runtime: `Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);`

Comment: `: double, long` means double *and* long - i.e., it's nonsensical.

Comment: The generic constraints is AND, not OR. So T in your case must be both double and long, which seems unlikely..!

Comment: I'm impressed that that would even compile

Comment: @Jonesopolis it doesn't compile; for one thing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dcw7ztt.aspx

Comment: @Blorgbeard no it does not. OP gave the impression it did.  I am dumb.

Comment: And what about this?: `T Value = (T)2.5;` if it's a double it will cast double to double and will set 2.5, if it's a long it will crop the decimals and will set 2.

Comment: People don't be nervous... It is one question do understand the rules on C#. Please take a look to my answer below... "And Get out of the box " Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three reason why your code won't work:

1. Your generic constraint requires that the type inherit from both `double` and `long` which is not possible
2. `double` and `long` cannot be used as generic constraints because they are sealed.
3. There's no implicit conversion from `double` to an unknown type

There's no "fix" for the first two.  The fix for the last one would be to cast to `object` first:

```
    if (isDouble)
    {
        T Value = (T)(object)2.5; // does not compile
        Result.Add(Value);
    }
    else
    {
        T Value = (T)(object)2; // does not compile
        Result.Add(Value);
    }
```

There's no way to get the method to work *exactly* the way you want it to because there's no way to constrain `T` to be either `double` or `long`.  You *could* inspect the type using reflection and throw an exception if it's not one of those, but there's no way to enforce that at compile-time.

The core problem is that *your code is not generic*.  True generic code does not care what `T` is (modulo some very broad parameter, like it must implement some interface).  The *caller* gets to determine what `T` is, not the method, so anything that has different logic based on the *actual* type of `T` is typically a code smell.  This seems to be just a learning exercise, but if you needed this functionality in real life I would recommend having two different methods:

```
private IList<double> GetDoubleList()
{
    IList<double> Result = new List<double>();

    double Value = 2.5; 
    Result.Add(Value);

    return Result;
}
private IList<long> GetLongList()
{
    IList<long> Result = new List<long>();

    long Value = 2; 
    Result.Add(Value);

    return Result;
}
```

It's not *that much* longer than what you started with, there's a little bit of repetition but not much, it's completely type safe, and there's no type ambiguity within the methods.

Next you can refactor out the redundant code into a generic method (in this case you don't need to constrain it since you control the types from the calling method):

```
private IList<T> GetList<T>(T Value)
{
    IList<T> Result = new List<T>();

    Result.Add(Value);

    return Result;
}
private IList<double> GetDoubleList()
{
    return GetList<double>(2.5);
}
private IList<long> GetLongList()
{
    return GetList<long>(2); 
}
```

Comment: The really bizarre thing is that I get an InvalidCastException with `T Value = (T)(object)2;`. The way I got around it was with `T Value = (T)(object)2L;`

Comment: That's because the _actual_ type is an `int` since it's an integer literal.  Since reference casts require that the _actual_ type be the compatible (rather than convertible) the cast will fail at run-time.

Comment: That's what I was figuring when I inspected it afterwards.

Comment: I'm in agreement with your edits, especially the final refactor that accepts any value. Having checks within the generic method defeats the purpose. I also agree that it seems to be a learning exercise.

Comment: Very nice example to keep the central idea in one method. That what I was looking... Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

isDouble is given a value at run-time. Both assignments must make sense at compile-time regardless of branching.

You are trying to do something with generics that can't be done in principle.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your answer, see: [Introduction to Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx)

As far as your current problem where you want only `double` or `long` to be handled, you can do as D Stanley suggested and just do something with the other types. Here's an example:

```
  private IList<T> GetGenericList<T>()
  {
     Type parmType = typeof(T);
     if (!parmType.Equals(typeof(double)) && !parmType.Equals(typeof(long)))
     {
        return null;
     }
     else
     {
        IList<T> Result = new List<T>();

        if (parmType.Equals(typeof(double)))
        {
           T Value = (T)(object)2.5;
           Result.Add(Value);
        }
        else
        {
           T Value = (T)(object)2L;
           Result.Add(Value);
        }

        return Result;
     }
  }
```

Now, when I use it like this:

```
     List<double> lDbl = (List<double>)GetGenericList<double>();
     List<long> lLng = (List<long>)GetGenericList<long>();
     List<string> lStr = (List<string>)GetGenericList<string>();
```

I end up with the expected values in `lDbl` and `lLng`, including the correct data types. However, `lStr` is set to `null` because that's how I have it handling types other than `double` or `long`. You could just as easily throw an exception in there.

Comment: Thanks Chris and Everyone!

Comment: What's with the casts? `List<double> lDbl = GetGenericList<double>();` should be fine, right?

Comment: It required explicit casting since it's returning `IList`. Otherwise, it'll give an implicit casting error. Actual usage may vary. That was just my quick hack.

Comment: @MarcosOto You're welcome! Be sure to check out D Stanley's refactored version. He did a pretty good job explaining why the original is not generic and how to do it. Mine was a quick hack while at work to directly address your issue.